# Skip "Capture Page Screenshot" for some keywords

Tags: appium, robotframework

I'm writing test cases in Robot Framework using [AppiumLibrary](http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html).

I'm importing AppiumLibrary with the following code to get a screenshot whenever something goes wrong:

```
AppiumLibrary.__init__(self, run_on_failure="Capture Page Screenshot")
```

Is there a way to NOT take a screenshot for a specific keyword? This keyword will for example create 15 screenshots (if it's not able to find Donald):

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    30 seconds    2 seconds    Element Text Should Be    Username    Donald
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to do what you want. There are many solutions, however.

One solution would be to turn off capturing the keyword (using [register keyword to run on failure](http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Register%20Keyword%20To%20Run%20On%20Failure)) immediately before calling `wait until keyword succeeds`. You could then call `wait until keyword succeeds`, and then turn capturing back on afterwards.

Or, you can register your own custom keyword instead of `Capture page screenshot`. Your own keyword can use whatever logic it wants to determine whether to capture screenshots or not. For example, it could look for a global variable that tells it whether to capture or not.

You could also write your own keyword to use in place of `wait until keyword succeeds` which also uses one of the other two solutions.

For example, create a keyword named `wait until element contains text` which turns off the capturing, runs `wait until keyword succeeds`, and then turns it back on. Then, in your test you still just have a single statement:

```
wait until element contains text  Username  Donald
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Register Keyword To Run On Failure   NONE       
${Status}   Run Keyword And Return Status   Wait Until Keyword Succeeds   30 seconds    2 seconds    Element Text Should Be    Username    Donald          
Register Keyword To Run On Failure    Capture Page Screenshot                                                                               
IF    ${Status}==False
      Element Text Should Be    Username    Donald
END
```

-Lets Walkthrough whats happening in the above code snippet

1. Register Keyword To Run On Failure   NONE (To avoid multiple
   screenshots when **Element Text Should Be** keyword fails in the
   next line )
2. After waiting for 30 seconds it will return status If the keyword passes it returns pass and if it fails it returns fails and gets stored in status variable (Remember no screenshots are generated in this process since we turned off screenshots in point 1.)
3. Again setting back **Capture Page Screenshot** Keyword on Failure to take screenshot.
4. Lastly one more time it will run **Element Text Should Be** and if it fails it generates a screenshot and keyword fails.(Since ${Status}==False that means it will run only if **Wait Until Keyword Succeeds** keyword fails otherwise this IF  block will not run since our keyword already passed)